# Where can I download the Unity.Burst package?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Need to download the Unity.Burst package.

I am trying to use the ECS and job system for my project. I am using Unity 2019.1.0f2 personal version on my MacBook. I realize that I need to add the unity.burst package which is not included in the default software. Where can I find it?

Comment: Before anyone answering the question. Thank you guys. I love people here.

Comment: You need to use the package manager window, and enable pre-release packages. Also, I am flagging this question since it's not about programming specifically. This would be a better fit in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Window -> Package Manager and let it show all available packages(not just currently installed ones). There you'll find the burst compiler. Click on install and voila.